# VBA Detect if an e-mail in editing mode has a signature included?

Tags: vba, outlook

I'm trying to add a signature but ensure that no other signature can be added after it. My method of adding it is basically concatenating the HTMLBody and a custom HTML-based signature.

As background, when I start writing an Outlook e-mail, I can attach a signature to it using Message → Include → Signature and picking the signature I need. However, no matter how many times I pick a signature, I won't get duplicates.

How does Outlook detects that a signature has been included? Is it a property under the MailItem object or the Inspector?

Thanks,

Comment: A signature is nothing but inserted text, so you must parse the body for (pieces of) text that uniquely will identify the signature you are about to insert/append.

Comment: @Gustav , so you are saying that the “Signature” commands compare the full string of the already present signature before it inserts a new one?

Comment: I played a little with this, and you are right. It must be the Outlook GUI that keeps track of it. You can edit the signature, and you can select another signature, and the first will be replaced. However, if you right-click and study the _Source_ of a sent mail, only the HTML has been left. So, you must handle it on the object level - as shown by @niton below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a bookmark when a user applies a signature.

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Sub signatureText()

Dim newEmail As mailItem
Dim olInsp As Inspector

Dim wdDoc As Object
Dim oRng As Object
Dim oBookmark As Object

Dim sigText As String

Set newEmail = CreateItem(olMailItem)
    
With newEmail

    Set olInsp = .GetInspector
    Set wdDoc = olInsp.WordEditor
    Set oRng = wdDoc.Range
    
    ' Default signature
    ' or set a breakpoint to manually add a signature
    .Display
    
    If wdDoc.Bookmarks.Exists("_MailAutoSig") Then
        Set oBookmark = wdDoc.Bookmarks("_MailAutoSig")
        
        sigText = oBookmark.Range.Text
        
        Debug.Print oBookmark.Range.Text
        MsgBox "Please do not add your own signature."
        
    Else
        Debug.Print "No signature bookmark."
    End If
    
End With
    
End Sub
```